# Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.BadVersion

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, serialization, flash-builder

Okay - So I've been looking all over the place to try and correct this problem - But I keep finding different answers, and frankly, it is getting terribly frustrating trying to figure this out. Lemme post some code for you to look at:

PHP Script:

```
public function addNewCompany(CompanyVO $item) 
{
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection,
    "INSERT INTO `companies` ('companyName') VALUES (?);");
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    mysqli_bind_param($stmt, 's', $item->companyName);
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    $autoid = mysqli_stmt_insert_id($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);
    mysqli_close($this->connection);
    return $autoid;
}
```

Portions of the MXML Main App:

```
protected function companysignupsheet1_addCompanyEventHandler(event:AddCompanyEvent):void
        {
            companyservicero.addNewCompany({Data:event.companyData});
        } 

<s:RemoteObject id="companyservicero"
                    source="CompanyServices"
                    destination="addNewCompany"
                    endpoint = "http://localhost/PHP_RO/public/gateway.php"
                    result="companyservicero_resultHandler(event)"
                    fault="companyservicero_faultHandler(event)"/>
```

A Part of code from Component:

```
            protected function button_submitNewCompany_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var companyData11:CompanyVO = new CompanyVO();
            companyData11.companyName = textinput_NewCompanyName.text;

            var eventObject:AddCompanyEvent = new AddCompanyEvent("addCompanyEvent", companyData11);
            dispatchEvent(eventObject);
        }
```

The Event:

```
     package events
     {
    import flash.events.Event;


    import valueObjects.CompanyVO;

    public class AddCompanyEvent extends Event
    {

    public var companyData:CompanyVO;

    public function AddCompanyEvent(type:String, companyData:CompanyVO)
    {
        super(type);
        this.companyData = companyData;
    }
}
}
```

If I need to post more I will be happy to do so. Also - I know it is a bit overkill to try and just send the one text value in this fashion, but there will be much, much more that will go with it when I get it working - I just was trying to focus on where the problem is. Oh - and I don't know if it helps at all...But currently I can retrieve records from the mySQL database this is attached to (although I am not doing that via the RemoteObject way) - I can also add to the same table using the old drag-and-drop (Connect to Data/Services) functionality of an exact copy of the PHP above (although with the information hard coded in (I.E. the CompanyName=testtest)).

And to finish it all off - earlier when I didn't define the datatype for the argument:

```
public function addNewCompany($item){.....
```

for addNewCompany - it DID add a record in the database, although it was blank and it would still popup an error message with the whole Channel.Connect, etc..... And now in Zend Server's logs it is saying that the data is getting transferred in a stdClass wrapper and it is needed in CompanyVO datatype.

I am sooo frustrated with this all - I've been stuck with this type of problems for about 2-3 days now and I give up! PLEASE help. Thank you so much for your time and assistance!

-CS

EDIT - MORE INFO

GATEWAY.PHP

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);
$webroot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$configfile = "$dir/amf_config.ini";
$servicesdir = $dir.'/../services';
$librarydir = $dir.'/../library';
//default zend install directory
$zenddir = $webroot.'/ZendFramework/library';
//Load ini file and locate zend directory
if (file_exists($configfile)) {
    $arr = parse_ini_file($configfile, true);
    if (isset($arr['zend']['webroot'])) {
        $webroot = $arr['zend']['webroot'];
        $zenddir = $webroot.'/ZendFramework/library';
    }
    if (isset($arr['zend']['zend_path'])) {
        $zenddir = $arr['zend']['zend_path'];
    }
    if (isset($arr['zend']['library'])) {
        $librarydir = $arr['zend']['library'];
    }
    if (isset($arr['zend']['services'])) {
        $servicesdir = $arr['zend']['services'];
    }
}
// Setup include path
// add zend directory, library and services to include path
set_include_path(get_include_path()
    .PATH_SEPARATOR.$zenddir
.PATH_SEPARATOR.$librarydir
.PATH_SEPARATOR.$servicesdir);
// Initialize Zend Framework loader
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->setFallbackAutoloader(true)-                          >suppressNotFoundWarnings(true);
// Load configuration
$default_config = new Zend_Config(array("production" => false), true);
$default_config->merge(new Zend_Config_Ini($configfile, 'zendamf'));
$default_config->setReadOnly();
$amf = $default_config->amf;
// Store configuration in the registry
Zend_Registry::set("amf-config", $amf);
// Initialize AMF Server
$server = new Zend_Amf_Server();
$server->setProduction($amf->production);
if (isset($amf->directories)) {
    $dirs = $amf->directories->toArray();
    foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
        if ($dir == "./") {
            $server->addDirectory($webroot);
        } else 
            if (realpath("{$webroot}/{$dir}")) {
                $server->addDirectory("{$webroot}/{$dir}");
            } else 
                if (realpath($dir)) {
                    $server->addDirectory(realpath($dir));
                }
    }
}
// Initialize introspector for non-production
if (! $amf->production) {
    $server->setClass('Zend_Amf_Adobe_Introspector', '', 
    array("config" => $default_config, "server" => $server));
    $server->setClass('Zend_Amf_Adobe_DbInspector', '', 
    array("config" => $default_config, "server" => $server));
}
// Handle request
echo $server->handle();
```

AMF_CONFIG

```
[zend]
;set the absolute location path of webroot directory, example:
;Windows: C:\apache\www
;MAC/UNIX: /user/apache/www
 webroot = "C:/Zend/Apache2/htdocs"

;set the absolute location path of zend installation directory, example:
;Windows: C:\apache\PHPFrameworks\ZendFramework\library
;MAC/UNIX: /user/apache/PHPFrameworks/ZendFramework/library
zend_path ="C:/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/.metadata/.plugins/org.zend.php.framework.resource/resources/ZendFramework-1/library"
library ="C:/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/PHP_RO/library"
services ="C:/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/PHP_RO/services"

[zendamf]
amf.production = false
amf.directories[]=PHP_RO/services
```

Comment: post your services config / channel definition xml pls?

Comment: I have no idea where that is. I've done searches on my system for it. The only one(s) I CAN find are gateway.php and amf_config. Maybe you're looking for one of these...? I'll post them and see if they are it.

Comment: UPDATE : Looking at the RAW view of what's being sent to the PHP script is:

Comment: ServiceRequest: addNewCompany; RemoteService; addNewCompany
(mx.messaging.messages::RemotingMessage)#0
  body = (Array)#1
    [0] (Object)#2
      CompanyVO = (valueObjects::CompanyVO)#3
        companyName = "asdf"
  clientId = (null)
  destination = ""
  headers = (Object)#4
    DSRemoteCredentials = ""
    DSRemoteCredentialsCharset = (null)
  messageId = "54D01758-6CE2-C4FC-58DF-340A73ABC0A7"
  operation = "addNewCompany"
  source = "CompanyServices"
  timestamp = 0
  timeToLive = 0

Answer (score 1):

Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.BadVersion usually happens when PHP echoes an error or warning to the amf response. Flex gets an amf message appended with something like 'warning something went wrong on line X' and can't parse it.
Turn on the network monitor in Flash Builder and view the latest raw response. You will see the error formatted with html tags.